# Email the pdf generated via highcharts export

Tags: jquery, email, highcharts

Is it possible to email the PDF generated by the highcharts export library?
Like we have export button at the top right corner of the map now if we want to download the chart as an image we click on the button and the image save popup opens, insted i want to email the image/pdf as an attachment via highcarts.
see link:

```
<code>http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/offline-download/</code>
```

Insted of download as PDF I want email PDF.

Comment: You would have to build this functionality yourself. You would have to save the file to the server, and build some sort of pop up with the controls to send the file, and an ajax call to your server to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we don't support sending charts with email from the export menu.

Please request this feature at Highcharts Uservoice, [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general).

On Uservoice we can easily which feature request are favourited by many  people and needs to be implemented.